# Nested if statement in PHP MySQL SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, performance, select, pdo

I need to cross-reference rows. If the row does not exist, then insert it.

Here are the criterias it needs to go through before it can be inserted into database:

> First find appointments that belong to the user (`user_id`).
>
> Then find appointments that match the appointment ID (`appointment_id`). If appointment ID DOES NOT exist, continue to the next step.
>
> If the appointment ID DOES NOT exist, then search if an appointment matches the appointment date AND time (`appointment_date`) (`appointment_time`).
>
> If it DOES NOT exist, then `INSERT` into database.

Here is my code so far. How can I make my nested if statements of `SELECT` faster and more simpler?

```
// Search for appointment by appointment ID to see if it already exists
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id AND appointment_id = :appointment_id LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $userId);
$stmt->bindParam(':appointment_id', $appointmentId);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// If appointment does not already exist, search for appointment by date and time
if(!$result) {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id AND appointment_date = :appointment_date AND appointment_time = :appointment_time LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $userId);
    $stmt->bindParam(':appointment_date', $appointmentDate);
    $stmt->bindParam(':appointment_time', $appointmentTime);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result2 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(!$result2) {
        // If appointment does not already exist, insert into database:
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO...")
    }
}
```

How can i make this faster and simpler/shorter?

Comment: How do you have an appointment ID if it hasn't been created yet?

Comment: @Devon The appointment ID is coming from another calendar. Im trying to sync two calendars

Comment: Consider using IODKU

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to differentiate between the two queries, just combine your conditions:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id AND 
 (appointment_id = :appointment_id OR 
  appointment_date = :appointment_date AND appointment_time = :appointment_time)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I do need to look by the appointment ID first, before looking by the appointment date and time

Comment: Ok, so then I don't really know what you're asking for in your question then.

Comment: I'm just cross referencing my calendar and another calendar. I'm trying to sync two calendars together. In my code, i'm trying to search for the same appointment/event on my calendar starting with the appointment id and if nothing is found, then by the date and time. If nothing is found from that, then the event will be inserted, as there are no existing appointments in the db

Comment: right, but if you need to do it in two steps then you already have your code...so what do you need?

Comment: I'm just wondering if there's a faster way to process all of this, especially if there are 100000+ appointments

Comment: According your code I really don't understand what for you need to separate it to 2 steps. If you try reduce execution time by searching firstly by user_id and then by date/time then you need to know, that MySQL optimizer work exactly in this way. I think @Devon's request is best way to do what you want.

Comment: Maybe you should add unique key user_id, appoinment_id to speed up search. Also you can use SQL from this answer but with little modification: 
SELECT id, appointment_id FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id AND 
 (appointment_id = :appointment_id OR 
  appointment_date = :appointment_date AND appointment_time = :appointment_time) ORDER BY appointment_id ASC . And then before inserting check appointment_id is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to use UNION to have only one query and half the code.

```
// Search for appointment by appointment ID to see if it already exists
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("(SELECT id FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id AND appointment_id = :appointment_id) UNION (SELECT id FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id AND appointment_date = :appointment_date AND appointment_time = :appointment_time) LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $userId);
$stmt->bindParam(':appointment_id', $appointmentId);
$stmt->bindParam(':appointment_date', $appointmentDate);
$stmt->bindParam(':appointment_time', $appointmentTime);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// If appointment does not already exist, search for appointment by date and time
if(!$result) {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO...")
}
```

I haven't really tested this code above. It might need some tweaking.

Tell me if something goes too awry.